# Why can't I use the result of a VLOOKUP in a formula in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I'm using VLOOKUP to return a value from a second sheet, which is working fine.

`=VLOOKUP(B7,Sheet2.A1:Sheet2.B40,2,0)`

However, If I try to use the value returned by this formula in another formula, I get the result of `#VALUE!`.

For example, Sheet1.B8 uses the above formula to get a value from the second sheet. If I then reference Sheet1.B8 in any mathematical formula (`=1 * Sheet1.B8`), the result is always `#VALUE!`.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I make this work?

Comment: What formula you are using that references Sheet1.B8 elsewhere?Can you mention that as well.

Comment: @pat2015 I've updated my post.  The problem occurs with any mathematical formula.

Comment: Is your VLOOKUP returning numeric value or it may be a text value?

Comment: If you are using . as the separator between sheet.cell that is the problem... It's sheet!cell --- I'm not sure why it's working in your vlookup formula.

Comment: Try formula say =1*VALUE(Sheet1.B8) and see what happens now

Comment: @Tyson If I use `!` as the separator, the result is `#NAME?`. When creating the formula, selecting the cell in Sheet2 autofills `Sheet2.A1`.

Comment: @pat2015 `Err:502`

Comment: @pat2015 Thanks for your help. You made me take a second look at the data in sheet2, and I found the problem.

Comment: Glad to know that it's now resolved and you figured it out eventually.

Comment: Oops.. I read the question too fast and without enough detail and gave an Excel answer, glad you worked it out tho

Answer (score 0):

Looking closer at the data in Sheet2, I noticed that the "numbers" were not actually being recognized as numbers.  When I pasted the data into the sheet, tabs and spaces were included in the cells. This caused the cells to be text, rather than numeric.

Not sure why the blank space was not removed when pasting the data, but removing it solved the problem.